# Lamb shift and logarithmic corrections

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, lamb-shift

Radiative corrections (Lamb shift) to the energy level (1S state) of a hydrogen atom can be written as a power series in $Z\alpha$ and $\ln(Z\alpha)$:
$$\Delta E = \frac{\alpha}{\pi}(Z\alpha)^4 \left[A_{40}+A_{41}\ln(Z\alpha)+Z\alpha A_{50}+A_{62}\ln^2(Z\alpha)+A_{61}\ln(Z\alpha)+A_{60}+\ldots\right]. $$

Is there a way to prove that $(Z\alpha)^5$ term does not contain logarithms, without actually calculating this term? What about higher order terms? Do we expect logs in $(Z\alpha)^7$ terms? 
Those logs usually indicate that the correction is sensitive to the low energy (infrared) part of the theory. Why $(Z\alpha)^5$ term does not care about infrared limit? 
What about $\left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right)^2$ corrections? Do they behave in the same way?